# Maximum call stack size exceeded with scatterjs and eosjs

Tags: eosjs, scatter

**Use in vue**

```
const eosOptions = { expireInSeconds: 60 }
const network ={
        blockchain: 'eos',
        protocol: 'http',
        host: 'jungle.cryptolions.io',
        port: 18888,     chainId:'038f4b0fc8ff18a4f0842a8f0564611f6e96e8535901dd45e43ac8691a1c4dca'
      }
const eos = scatter.eos(network, Eos, eosOptions)
eos.getBlock()
```

**Error in browser**

```
runtime.js:138 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.create (<anonymous>)
    at Object.runtime.mark (runtime.js:138)
    at eval (index.js:1)
    at Object.eval (index.js:1)
    at eval (index.js:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.eval (index.js:1)
    at eval (index.js:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.eval (index.js:1)
```